# Syntax error python windows mp4dash.py

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I'm trying to encode video using mp4dash on windows 7. Downloaded sdk and after running the command:

```
mp4dash --widevine-header provider:widevine_test#content_id:2a --encryption-key 90351951686b5e1ba222439ecec1f12a:0a237b0752cbf1a827e2fecfb87479a2 vid_bigbuckbunny2.mp4
```

I get Syntax error at this line:

```
print 'Parsing media file', str(file_list_index)+':', GetMappedFileName(media_file)
```

Comment: probably python 3 vs python 2 print. Try adding parentheses.

Comment: Thank you that was the issue.